# How to redirect with cowboy_rest

Tags: rest, erlang, cowboy

I am having trouble with how to redirect with cowboy_rest with GET request. Is there any way to set the <<"location">> in header to response to browser by cowboy_rest?

The redirect is made in the cowboy_rest with POST method is
{{ok, URL_to_redirect}, Req, State}

But I cannot find a way to redirect with GET method even <<"location">> is set in the header of cowboy_req.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cowboy_req:reply/4` and `{halt, Req, State}` to stop execution:

```
{ok, NewReq} = cowboy_req:reply(
                 302,
                 [{<<"Location">>, <<"http://www.redirect-url.com">>}],
                 <<>>,
                 Req),
{halt, NewReq, State}
```

Comment: Thank P_A, and the proper redirect code is 307. As I use the cowboy_rest (RESTful) handle so no need to have {halt, NewReq, State}. and feel strange why it doesn't need to add {halt, NewReq, State}.

Answer (score 0):

The headers is a map now

```
{ok, NewReq} = cowboy_req:reply(
                 302,
                 #{<<"Location">> => <<"http://www.redirect-url.com">>},
                 <<>>,
                 Req),
{halt, NewReq, State}
```